# Batch Copy Cover Art from One Song to Another (Identical File Names)

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, mp3, id3, aac

I'm looking for a way to copy the album art from one set of songs to another set of the same songs that don't have the album art. FFMPEG copies the text tags (artist, album, title...) perfectly, but will not copy the embedded album artwork.

I've been trying to batch convert my folder of MP3s into 128k AAC (using FFMPEG and the `libfdk-aac` codec) files to save space on my phone, but it hasn't copied my album art over to the new songs.
I used the following batch command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.mp3') DO ffmpeg -i "%%G" -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k "%%~nG.m4a"
```

EDIT: I tried using the following command to test it out, because stream 0:0 is the audio, and stream 0:1 is the JPEG, however it did not work:

```
ffmpeg -i Estranged.mp3 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -c:v copy Estranged.m4a
```

Here's a paste of the log: http://pastebin.com/dZFsvR7F (I know, it's not the latest version. I had trouble compiling it myself but I'm currently working on it.)

Is there a way to copy the album art (or entire tag, if need be) from songs with an identical name in one folder to the songs in the new folder?

I.E. `C:\Folder1\song.mp3` → `C:\Folder2\song.m4a`

Thanks.

Comment: Is the art embedded in the file or external?

Comment: Would it help to say that `%%~nG` will select the name part of the filename in `%%G`? See `for /?|more` for details...

Comment: The art is embedded for all the files soja. And thanks for explaining it Magoo, I was unsure why it was formatted that way.

Comment: On older versions of FFMPEG you can use the additional switch "-vcodec copy" to preserve cover art between the source and the target format.

Comment: It works! But not for AAC... I used `ffmpeg-hi10-heaac -i Estranged.mp3 -vcodec copy -c:a libmp3lame -b:a 128k Estranged-COPY.mp3` (I was able to use `acodec` and `c:a` interchangeably) and it worked - other than the fact that Windows wouldn't recognize the tag, but it was there in AudioShell. However, when I tried to convert to AAC with `ffmpeg-hi10-heaac -i Estranged.mp3 -vcodec copy -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k Estranged-COPY.m4a`, I got `Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument`. I suspect it's the M4A container that's the issue here.

Comment: Also worth noting I got this other error higher up: `[ipod @ 040c83e0] Could not find tag for codec mjpeg in stream #0, codec not currently supported in container`. Here's the paste: [http://pastebin.com/mb7pemA6](http://pastebin.com/mb7pemA6)

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -y -i input1.mp3 -i input2.mp3
-map 1 -codec copy 
-map 0:1 -map_metadata 0  -id3v2_version 3
o.mp3
```

takes audio from input 2

takes metadata and album cover from input 1 in the highly-compatible id3v2.3 format

this is to be modified as needed

Comment: Be careful, this copy ALL metadata from the song with cover, removing song name and other data.